# Issue with setting up hibernate with Dropwizard 0.7.1. "Unable to create a hibernate session on 0.7.1"

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

I am unable to create hibernate session in 0.7.1. I know I am not creating hibernate session right. But cant figure out where am I going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

```
ERROR:
! org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context
! at org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContext.currentSession(ManagedSessionContext.java:75) ~[userengine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014) ~[userengine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

The Application file:

```
public class UserEngineApplication extends Application<UserEngineConfiguration>{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new UserEngineApplication().run(args);
}

private final HibernateBundle<UserEngineConfiguration> hibernateBundle =
        new HibernateBundle<UserEngineConfiguration>(Persons.class) {
            @Override
            public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory (UserEngineConfiguration configuration) 
            {
                return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
            }
};

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<UserEngineConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(hibernateBundle);
}

@Override
public void run(UserEngineConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {

    final PersonDAO personsdao = new PersonDAO(hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
        environment.jersey().register(new PersonsResource(personsdao));
}
}
```

The Configuration file:

```
public class UserEngineConfiguration extends Configuration {
@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty
private DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();

@JsonProperty("database")
public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
    return database;
}

@JsonProperty("database")
public void setDataSourceFactory(DataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory)
{
    this.database = dataSourceFactory;
}
}
```

YAML file:

```
database:
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  user: user
  password: pass
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Tryout
```

Some links that I tried:

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-example.

[how to auto-wire HibernateBundle with guice on dropwizard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320927/how-to-auto-wire-hibernatebundle-with-guice-on-dropwizard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It worked after adding `@UnitOfWork` annotation on the resource methods.